# Trying to install Scrapy - error: Could not find 'openssl.exe'

Tags: python, pip, scrapy, pyopenssl

Any thoughts on how to fix this problem?  I am using pip to install Scrapy on a Win XP Pro SP 3 machine.  I have Python 2.7 installed on the machine.  There seems to be a problem with pyOpenSSL.  I am getting a "Could not find 'openssl.exe'" error.

Here is my log file.  I had to hack it up a little because of the URLs in it.

---

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Scrapy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.14.4-py2.7.egg

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Twisted>=2.5 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from Scrapy)

  Downloading from URL pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/w3lib/w3lib-1.2.tar.gz#md5=f929d5973a9fda59587b09a72f185a9e (from pypi.python.org/simple/w3lib/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package w3lib

    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\w3lib.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\w3lib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\w3lib.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\w3lib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\w3lib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\w3lib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\w3lib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  Source in c:\ray\dist\pip-1.1\build\w3lib has version 1.2, which satisfies requirement w3lib (from Scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking pyOpenSSL (from Scrapy)


  Downloading from URL pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz#md5=767bca18a71178ca353dff9e10941929 (from pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyOpenSSL

    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


    error: Could not find 'openssl.exe'
```

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info

writing pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



error: Could not find 'openssl.exe'
```

---

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Ray\dist\pip-1.1\build\pyOpenSSL

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 245, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1009, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 225, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\__init__.py", line 256, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Ray\dist\pip-1.1\build\pyOpenSSL
```

Comment: Is openssl in your Windows `PATH`.

Answer (score 9):

you can just goto http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL/0.13 and download the windows installer, after that, continue your scrapy install.